# Background Intelligent Transfer Service , the same network, how to set remoteURL

Tags: c++, c, msdn, microsoft-bits

I am working with Background Intelligent Transfer Service(BITS) and with files from the same computer it works well for example:

```
remoteURL = C:\file.wav
localFile = C\Debug\file.wav
```

. But my question how to set remoteURL with network with 2 computers.

```
Server is 192.168.1.2
Client is 192.168.1.3
```

I tried: 
`remoteURL = \\192.168.1.2\\file"` -> doesnt work
`remoteURL = \\computerName\\file"` -> doesnt work

I tried share folder and use BITS also doesnt work.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help !!

Comment: Shouldn't it be "\\remote-computer-name\shared-folder-name\file"?

Comment: will try this and respond ASAP

Comment: it gaves me error

Comment: I discover that bytesTotal field is VERY LARGE ...